# How do I make a code that requires variables, assign values to variables, create a document.write that outputs the values for each string?

Tags: javascript

I am working on a code for JavaScript in Notepad++. My program wants me to create four variables named string1, string2, string3 and string4. Assign the value start to string1. Assign the return value of a prompt() method as the value for string2. Assign the return value of a confirm() method as the value for string3. Assign the value end to string4.

In the second block, in body section create a document.write() statement that outputs the values of each of the four variables created in the first JavaScript block. Experiment with different methods of ensuring that a space exists between each value.  After the code is working properly, determine a way to output the four variable values on separate lines of the XHTML page.

Here is a copy of the code I am working on.  I run this in Notepad++ and the code shows up in the browser.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>Application Project Lesson 2</title>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    var string1 = "start";
    var string2 = "prompt()";
    var string3 = "confirm()";
    var string4 = "end";

    </head>
  </script>

  <body>
    <h3>Hello, World</h3>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      document.write("Hello, World.")
      document.write("start") + prompt(), "  + confirm(), ""end.");

      </body>
    </script>

</html>
```

Comment: This sound suspiciously like a homework assignment. Also, you have mismatched `<script>` and `<head>` tags, along with too many brackets on your second `document.write()` line.

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: Well where you define your 4 strings is not what your teacher wants you to do.

Comment: You should consider using an IDE with a javascript web plugin, javascript can be ridiculously a pain to debug and plugins that highlight potential syntax issues with an IDE as well as highlight bracket sets used in code are invaluable. Consider http://www.eclipse.org and then download a node.js plugin or something that helps with javascript projects.

Comment: If you want to assigne the returned value of a function to a variable then you don't need to put them in the quotation (that's a string instead of calling the method). Also, you have mismatched brackets and write those functions you are trying to call.